# How can compute monthly average price of an invoice in ORACLE (Varray&loop)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table for invoices and there are millions of data. In my table, there are invoices and their first and last dates for customers. My target is to compute monthly average price of the invoices. For instance i have:

```
CUSTOMER_ID     INVOICE_ID    FIRST_DATE     LAST_DATE     AMOUNT_OF_INVOICE
9876543          1a           1 Jan 2017     17 Jan 2017         32$
9876543          1b          17 Jan 2017     10 Feb 2017         72$
9876543          1c          10 Feb 2017     7 March 2017        100$
9876543          1d          7 March 2017    1 April 2017        25$
9870011          2a           1 Jan 2017     10 Jan 2017         18$
9870011          2b          10 Jan 2017     10 Feb 2017         62$
9870011          2c          10 Feb 2017     1 April 2017        50$


my target is:

CUSTOMER_ID        MONTH         MONTHLY_AVERAGE_PRICE
9876543         January 2017         77$                 (=16x2+15x3)
9876543         February 2017        103$                (=9x3+19x4)
9876543         March 2017           49$                 (=6x4+25x1)
9870011         January 2017         62$                 (=9x2+22x2)
9870011         February 2017        37$                 (=9x2+19x1)
9870011         March 2017           31$                 (=31x1)
```

For instance I compute 77$  (`=16x2+15x3`) by:
First invoice which INVOICE_ID is `1a` there are 16 days from 1 Jan 2017 to 17 Jan 2017 (not incuding 17 Jan). And the price of invoice is 32$. Therefore average price for one day is 32/16 = 2$. The second invoice is `1b` and there are 24 days from 17 Jan 2017 to 10 Feb 2017. Therefore average consumption per day is 3$. And the part of this invoice for January is 15 days (From 17 January to 31 January including 31 January). All in all, for January average consumption: 16x2$+15x3$=77$.

Here I think, I have to use varray for storage the data on months and I have to use a loop to find the days between `FIRST_DATE` and `LAST_DATE`. However I couldn't do it. Or are there in other ways?

Comment: how you get 77$  .?  . and what's mean  (=16.2+15.3)?  your question is not clear ..

Comment: Oh sorry. First invoice which INVOICE_ID is 1a there are 16 days from 1 Jan 2017 to 17 Jan 2017 (not incuding 17 Jan). And the price of invoice is 32$. Therefore average price for one day is 32/16 = 2$.    The second invoice is 1b and there are 24 days from 17 Jan 2017 to 10 Feb 2017. Therefore average consumption per day is 3$. And the part of this invoice for January is 15 days (From 17 January to 31 January including 31 January). All in all for January average consumption: 16.2$+15.3$=77$. Is it clear right now? If not I can explain more.. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Query**:

```
WITH month_invoices ( c_id, i_id, first_date, last_date, month_start, month_end, amount )
AS (
  SELECT customer_id,
         invoice_id,
         first_date,
         last_date,
         first_date,
         LEAST( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( first_date, 'MM' ), 1 ), last_date ),
         amount_of_invoice
  FROM   your_table
UNION ALL
  SELECT c_id,
         i_id,
         first_date,
         last_date,
         month_end,
         LEAST( ADD_MONTHS( month_end, 1 ), last_date ),
         amount
  FROM   month_invoices
  WHERE  month_end < last_date
)
SELECT c_id AS customer_id,
       TRUNC( month_start, 'MM' ) AS month,
       SUM( amount * ( month_end - month_start ) / ( last_date - first_date ) )
         AS average_monthly_price
FROM   month_invoices
GROUP BY c_id, TRUNC( month_start, 'MM' )
ORDER BY customer_id, month;
```

**Output**:

```
CUSTOMER_ID MONTH      AVERAGE_MONTHLY_PRICE
----------- ---------- ---------------------
    9876543 2017-01-01                    77
    9876543 2017-02-01                   103
    9876543 2017-03-01                    49
    9870011 2017-01-01                    62
    9870011 2017-02-01                    37
    9870011 2017-03-01                    31
```

Comment: Thank you. This code is wonderful :) I'm asking for understand. I can't understand the part :                  UNION ALL
  SELECT c_id,
         i_id,
         first_date,
         last_date,
         month_end,
         LEAST( ADD_MONTHS( month_end, 1 ), last_date ),
         amount
  FROM   month_invoices
  WHERE  month_end < last_date

Comment: @Abdullah It is a recursive sub-query factoring clause (also known as a recursive CTE). The top part `SELECT ... FROM your_table` generates the data for the first month for each row in the original table and then the second part `UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM month_invoices` recurses to generate the remaining months for each row in the original table. The last bit `SELECT ... FROM month_invoices GROUP BY ...` then totals it for each month.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was great information for me. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.
The inner query creates a row for each day of each invoice.
The outer query sums them up.
It assumes that invoices will only be a maximum of 999 days long.

```
select customer_id, month, sum(average_cost_per_day) average_cost_per_day
from (
  select max(customer_id) customer_id,
         invoice_id,
         to_char(first_date + n-1, 'MONTH YYYY') month,
         count(1)*max(amount_of_invoice)/max(last_date-first_date) average_cost_per_day
  from your_table
  inner join (
    select level n
    from dual
    connect by level <= 1000
  )
  on (first_date + n-1 < last_date)
  group by invoice_id, to_char(first_date + n-1, 'MONTH YYYY')
)
group by customer_id, month
order by customer_id desc, to_date(month,'MONTH YYYY');
```